# What can be said about $f(x)$ having $f(x-1)=f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm asked to answer this question:

> Let $f$ be a polynomial function not equal to zero, what can be said about $f(x)$ having $f(x-1)=f(x)$

Which has four choices, $f(x)$ is an odd or even or negative or positive function.

What I've done is finding out that $f(1)=f(0)$ and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Let $f(0)=c$. By what you did, $f(1)=c$. By putting $x=2$, $f(2)=c$. By putting $x=3$, $f(3)=c$. And so on. But a polynomial of degree $n$ is completely determined by its values at $n+1$ points. So $f(x)=c$ for all $x$. Thus $f$ is even. It **could** be also odd (if $c=0$), or negative (if $c$ is, or positive (if $c$ is), but does not **need** to be.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks, that solves the problem as a complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** If $c$ is a zero of $f$, then so is $c-1$, $c-2$, ...

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Or if you're uncomfortable assuming that $f$ has a zero, consider the polynomial $f(x)-f(0)$.

Comment: @zizi A number $c$ is said to be a zero of a polynomial $f$ if $f(c) = 0$. In other words, $c$ is a root/solution of the polynomial equation $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @Srivatsan I see, I misinterpreted the answer, sorry. It means that  $\forall x: f(x)=c \neq 0$. Am I right? so all of the above can be true about $f$ except being odd.

Comment: @zizi You are using $c$ in a different sense. Dan's hint implies that $f(x)$ is a constant $C$ independent of $x$; moreover the question says that this constant $C$ is nonzero. Thus $f(x)$ is certainly always even and never odd. As to the other two options, depending on $C$, $f(x)$ could be always positive or always negative; this cannot be deduced unless we are told the sign of $C$. So, if exactly one option is correct, then that ought to be "even". [Note: I am using $C$ to denote the constant, since $c$ is used by Dan to denote the zeroes.]

Comment: @Srivatsan Got it, thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer so that I can accept it? It's not homework, I need to know the whole solution.

Comment: zizi, could you be more specific about what part you do not understand?